# Entity framework 6.1.3 NuGet license

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What is the correct license for the Entity framework 6.1.3 nugget used in my solution [downloaded from here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework)?

- The [EntityFramework codeplex page](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/license) is referring to the "Apache License 2.0 (Apache)
- NuGet has this [license link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320539), that redirects to [MICROSOFT SOFTWARE LICENSE TERMS](https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/net_library_eula_enu.htm)

Comment: My guess is that the source code is licensed under the Apache License, and the binaries (nuget package) are licensed under the Microsoft Software License.